# Open cover of $(0,1)$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose the open interval $(0,1)$ is given absolute value topology. Form $\{U_n \}$, $n=1,2,3…$, where $U_n=(\frac{1}{n+1},1)$. Prove that $\{U_n \}$ is an open cover of $(0,1)$ for all $n∈N$. Show that no finite number of $U_n$ cover $(0,1)$, even though any finite number of the $U_n$ may be omitted and what remains still give an open cover of $(0,1)$

here is what I got

Suppose $X=(0,1)$ and $U_n=(\frac{1}{n+1},1)$ for $n∈N$. Notice that

$\cup _{n=1}^\infty U_n = (\frac {1}{2},1) \cup (\frac {1}{3},1) \cup (\frac {1}{4},1)....=(0,1)$

This shows that  $\{U_n \}$ is an open cover of $(0,1)$ for all $n∈N$.

I don't know how to show the second part of this problem.

Comment: Topology is not my forté but I would assume there is a finite cover, take the greatest $N$ and consider a point in the interval $(0, 1/N)$. Something along these lines, I don't know how to write it.

Comment: I guess you don't want to use the Borel-Lebesgue theorem and the fact that $(0,1)$ isn't compact.

Comment: Nope, I haven't learnt that yet :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof of why it is actually a cover is not satisfactory, IMHO. Provide an argument. Key fact: for every $x>0$ we can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < x$ (why?).

Note that the $U_n$ are nested: if $n < m$, then $\frac{1}{m} < \frac{1}{n}$ and so $U_n \subset U_m$ (if $x$ is bigger than $\frac{1}{n}$, it's certainly bigger than $\frac{1}{m}$..).

So a finite subcover has the same union as the one with the largest index. And no $U_n$ covers $(0,1)$, as $\frac{1}{2n} \notin U_n$, e.g.

Comment: because $\frac{1}{n} >0$, so the only way to have $x <\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in N$is $x<0$, am I correct?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif In fact $x \le 0$. Hint: this follows from the fact that the natural numbers are unbounded above in $\mathbb{R}$ (Archimedian property)...

Comment: I'm not sure that I've learnt this property.I'm in the spring break and this chapter is self-study so I will be appreciated if you would explain it a little more.

Comment: Suppose $x>0$, then $\frac{1}{x} > 0$ as well, and so $n \in \mathbb{N}$ exists with $\frac{1}{x} < n$, by the unboundedness of $\mathbb{N}$. But then $\frac{1}{n} < x$ by standard properties of inequalities (divide both sides by $n$ and multiply both sides by $x(>0)$ which preserves the $<$-relation). But maybe that's overly formal. It's in fact just the proof of $\lim_n \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$, which is what we really use here.

Comment: ok, first what is IMHO? second, are you trying to use knowledge from advanced calculus to prove this problem? or you just want to prove that $X \subset \cup U_n$?

Comment: Well, you need some knowledge of $\mathbb{R}$ to show $X \subset \cup_n U_n$. But it needs some argument, depending on how deep one wants to go..

Answer (score 1):

Your proof that the $U_n$ cover $(0,1)$ isn't really that informative. You need to say why the union is the whole of $(0,1)$, and for that you need to show that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n\subset (0,1)$ and also $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n\supset (0,1)$. One is easier than the other.

To show that no finite set of the $U_n$s can cover $(0,1)$, suppose $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i\mid i\in I\}$ for some finite subset $I$ of $\mathbb{N}$. Now suppose that $N$ is the maximum of the set of natural number $i$ such that $U_i$ is in our assumed cover $\mathcal{U}$ - so $N=\max I$ - (why does this maximum exist?). Can you see how $U_N$ contains $U_i$ for all $i\in I$? What does this say about $\cup\mathcal{U}$?

Comment: The maximum exist be cause $N$ is a countable set, and Since $N \geq i$, $U_i \subset U_N$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a countable set but has no maximum so that doesn't seem like it will work.